# Pandas : How to save pandas dataframe to existing PDF ? or How to transfer pandas dataframe to PDF?

Tags: pandas, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a graph which I plotted and saved as PDF in my drive. Now I want to add a dataframe (5 columns) as second page to that PDF. How can it be done?

I searched a lot but couldnt find great solution. Is there any method to save in existing PDF or any method to save dataframe in new PDF?

Comment: May I ask what do you need this for? PDF isn't a format to exchange tabular data like a DataFrame. Are you publishing a paper and need to include the dataframe in an appendix?

Comment: Yes. I have lot of graphs based on dataframe. Its like two pager document. 1st page will be a graph and 2nd page will be a dataframe referring to that graph.

Comment: I think exporting your dataframe to Excel and covert the XLSX to PDF is an easier path. You will likely need some formatting, scaling to make it fit in one page, etc. Doing it by hand isn’t fun

Answer (score 0):

Use PDFPages. Each time you call plt.close() you will get a new page. So, draw your figure, call plt.close(), then draw the Pandas dataframe as a table using ax.table() and then call plt.close() again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

def _draw_as_table(df, pagesize):
    alternating_colors = [['white'] * len(df.columns), ['lightgray'] * len(df.columns)] * len(df)
    alternating_colors = alternating_colors[:len(df)]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=pagesize)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
    the_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,
                        rowLabels=df.index,
                        colLabels=df.columns,
                        rowColours=['lightblue']*len(df),
                        colColours=['lightblue']*len(df.columns),
                        cellColours=alternating_colors,
                        loc='center')
    return fig
  

def dataframe_to_pdf(df, filename, pagesize=(11, 8.5)):
  with PdfPages(filename) as pdf:
      # page 1: draw your current figure
      ...
      plt.close()

      # page 2: draw the table
      fig = _draw_as_table(page, pagesize)
      pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')      
      plt.close()
```